# can I grant rw permissions to a directory to one user on linux without modifying current ones?

Tags: linux, permissions

let's say the current permissions are www-data:www-data and I do not want to touch that. I am not sure if the web server would like that.

On the other hand I do not want to add this new user to www-data group as I want him to have access to only some website data directories.

Is anything like that possible on linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with extended ACLs. [Click here for a quick article.](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6091748.html)

Comment: that looks very good. How can I check if the current kernel supports ACL?

Comment: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/acl.htm That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: one more question :-) if I enable ACL support on ext3 nothing would change in terms of current permissions, doesn't it.

Comment: Don't quote me.  But enabling ACL will not effect your current permissions.  I have done it in the past without issue.